# Using Async/Await with Knex migrations

Tags: async-await, knex.js

I am using Knex migrations with regular promise methods, like this:

```js
exports.up = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema
        .hasTable('table_name')
        .then(function (exists) {
            if (!exists) {
                return knex
                    .schema
                    .createTable('table_name', function (table) {
                        table.increments('id').primary();
                    })
                    .then(console.log('created table_nametable'));
            }
        });
};
```

How would I refactor this to use async/await? The overall structure, where we are returning knex.schema with a chain of promise methods is throwing me for a loop.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should do:

```js
exports.up = async function (knex) {  
    if (! (await knex.schema.hasTable('table_name')) ) {
      await knex.schema.createTable('table_name', function (table) {
        table.increments('id').primary();
      });
    }

    // awaiting sequentially multiple promises to resolve one by one
    for (let item of arrayOfStuffToAwait) {
      await item;
    }
}

exports.down = async function (knex) {  
  await knex.schema.dropTable('table_name');
}
```